# Bootstrap grid not filling parent height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a bootstrap grid that is the UI of a calculator, and it is nested in a div that is sized at 100vw and 100vh. I set the size properties of the bootstrap container to height: 50% and width: 20%, but the content is only filling the width I set, not the height.

I want the height of the grid to resize dynamically so that it is 50% of it's container always.

https://gyazo.com/940d7d3aa77c464e351970bdbd5271b7 (the black line is the border that I am wanting the grid to fill to)

`

```
return (
      <div
        style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
        class="d-flex align-items-center"
      >
        <div style={{ height: "50%", width: "20%"}} class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-6">
              <p>AC</p>
            </div>
            <div class=" col col-3">
              <p>/</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-3">
              <p>x</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <p>7</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <p>8</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <p>9</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <p>-</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <p>4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <p>5</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <p>6</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <p>+</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-9">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-4">
                  <p>1</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col col-4">
                  <p>2</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col col-4">
                  <p>3</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col col-8">
                  <p>0</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col col-4">
                  <p>.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col col-3">
              <p>=</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`